# Making itms-services link more secure

Tags: ios, in-house-distribution

I am developing an in-house enterprise application with iOS and am slightly concerned about security. If anyone intercepts the URL containing the IPA file then they will be able to download and use the file. Is there any way of making this more secure? I know I can put the link behind a login system but if someone copies the URL and shares it, others will be able to download.

http://example.com/ manifest.plist">Install App

Comment: Normally you would secure the web host with the enterprise user credentials, so even if the link is copied then the user still needs an enterprise username/password.  You could also consider deploying the app via an MDM so that the link is never exposed.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to achieve this is to have temporary credentials as URL Parameter! (Authorization Header don't work so forget about oauth).

The security (user, password, token, etc) has to come from the backend.

And more: http is not working. You need https (in detail TLS>=1.2) and trusted TLS certifactes (selfsigned not working).